# How to backtrace debug a magento object

Tags: php, magento, xdebug

They gave me some tasks over a huge site realized with Magento.
I use Netbeans with Xdebug to debug (I'm on lubuntu oneiric btw) and I'm finding myself quite fine with all my tasks.
It happened to me to face a task concerning a class redeclaration and I lost a lot of time in finding the right file to change.

Just to learn how to do it correctly:
the task was to change the meta keywords, starting from a code like

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getKeywords()) ?>" />
```

With Netbeans debugger I can easily open the file containing getKeywords() which has:

```
public function getKeywords()
{
    if (empty($this->_data['keywords'])) {
        $this->_data['keywords'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/head/default_keywords');
    }
    return $this->_data['keywords'];
}
```

Now I couldn't find an easy way to go on through debugging in both cases :(
In particular my case is that `$this->_data['keywords']` is not empty on the page I had to correct .. 

so how can I easily know how this object is created and in particular who fills `_data['keywords']`?
It took me long time to find the right file by myself.

I'm not so expert in debugging, so maybe I could do it with netbeans w/ xdebug, but I cannot figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

open up terminal and

```
grep 'setKeywords(' app/code/ -rsn
```

this will reveal you the locations where this variable is set or used

Comment: Excellent use of lateral thinking.

Answer (score 0):

`grep -ri "Keywords" * | grep -v cache`

**'-r'** means recursive
**'-i'** means case insensitive
**'*'** means any file name
**'| grep -v cache'** means strip out any references into the cache directory

Answer (score 0):

You could temporarily create the method:

```
public function setKeywords($s) {

    echo sprintf('<pre>%s</pre>', print_r(debug_backtrace(), true));
    exit;
}
```

Add this code to same class that has getKeywords() so that when someone adds data via this function, you will see the backtrace and figure out how it happened